# IsNotNull Access function

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to set a function that retur value if two conditions are satisfied

I have four textboxes:

- `PCA`
- `Text151`
- `Text152`
- `Text153`

I made `Text153` to return `--` if `Text151` & `Text152` are null, and to return `Abs` if `Text151` is null and `Text152` is not null, else return `[PCA]`.

```
=IIf(IsNull([Text151]) and IsNull([Text152]), "--",IIf(IsNull([Text151]) and IsNotNull([Text152]),"Abs","[PCA]))
```

The function shows only `--` but the others expected returns could not be shown.

Comment: There isn't a ISNOTNULL function - you need NOT(ISNULL([Text152]))

Answer (score 0):

When testing for null in a query, always use the more efficient `is null` and `is not null` SQL keywords, rather than the less efficient `isNull` VBA function.

Hence, your expression may become:

```
=iif([text151] is null and [text152] is null,"--",iif([text151] is null and [text152] is not null,"Abs",[PCA]))
```

Note that this could also be written:

```
=iif([text151] is null,iif([text152] is null,"--","Abs"),[PCA])
```

As you only need to test whether the textbox is null once.